# terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error) when reducing an array with openmp

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int Nx = 500, Ny = 5000;
    double **arr = new double*[Nx];
    for (int x = 0; x < Nx; ++x) {
        arr[x] = new double[Ny]();
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < Nx; ++x) {
         #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:arr[x][:Ny])
         for (int y = 0; y < Ny; ++y) {
             arr[x][y] += 1;
         }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < Nx; ++x) {
        delete[] arr[x];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Tried googling but didn't find anything related to openMP. Why am I getting this error? How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it doesn't know how to handle `arr[x]`. Try `double *tmp = arr[x]` and use that in the pragma.

Comment: @paleonix Indeed with temporary array it works, i already knew it. I posted this here because i don't want temporary arrays

Comment: Generally it is discouraged to use 2D arrays like this because performance will be awful due to memory locality, pointer chasing etc. Use a 1D array instead and use the proper indexing (`arr[x * Ny + y]`). Then it should also be easy to specify the right section of that 1D array.

Comment: `tmp` is a pointer into the existing array, not an array itself. It should not cause any overhead.

Comment: @paleonix arr[x * Ny + y], is less readable than arr[x][y]

Comment: @Peter -- *arr[x * Ny + y], is less readable than arr[x][y]* -- Your method of creating the 2D array is still awful.   If you really and truly want to stick with the `[][]` syntax of a 2D array, then [this is an improvement to what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: "arr[x * Ny + y], is less readable than arr[x][y]" That is way C++23 finally comes with multidimensional subscript operators and `std::mdspan` using these. Until then we will have to make do with inline functions/functors or macros e.g. `arr[2D_index(x, y, Nx, Ny)]`.

Comment: Alternatively, we can wrap this in a class that benefit from C++ operators. Some libraries already do that like Eigen for example.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of `reduction(+:arr[x][:Ny])` here. The intent is not clear to me. The sequential code just do a `+=1` to all items so the parallel implementation of this is just a parallel for. If this is not the case, then the sequential code should be modified too. In OpenMP, the semantic of a code is the same with or without directives. Ignoring all directive is a perfectly valid (but useless) implementation. As it is, the reduction clause does not match with the sequential code so a compiler is free to generate a wrong code (as it is your job to give correct directives).